Failed to load image with Glide
I want to load an image and show it in an AlertDialog with custom view, and I get this error:

Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler in your application and a @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored

However, Glide documentation doesn't require the annotation processor dependency, unless you want to use integration libraries or configure Gradle.

Skip this if you don't want to use integration libraries or configure Glide

Hence, I am a bit confused: why should I use the annotation processor? Am I using integration libraries? Or am I configuring Glide?
My Fragment:
val myUriString: String = <path_to_my_bitmap>
val myDialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.myDialog, null)
val myImage = myDialogView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.my_image)
Glide.with(requireActivity()).load(Uri.parse(myUriString)).into(myImage)
val myDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(root.context)                                     
    .setTitle("My Dialog Title")                                           
    .setNegativeButton("Neg", null)                                            
    .setPositiveButton("Pos") {}
    .setView(myDialogView)
    .create()

my_dialog.xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="16dp" />
</LinearLayout>

